# echo .filetoignore >> .gitignore adds spaces between each character in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to add a line to my .gitignore file from Powershell.

When I run this in git bash or command prompt:

`echo .filetoignore >> .gitignore`

it correctly adds this line to my .gitignore file:

`.filetoignore`

when I run the same command from Powershell, it adds a space between every character:

`. f i l e t o i g n o r e`

What is the proper way to perform this operation in Powershell and add this line to .gitignore?

`.filetoignore`

Comment: `Add-Content .gitignore ".fieldtoignore"`

Answer (score 2):

It is encoding problem.
Windows internally works with strings in 2 byte encoding always.

Avoid using `>>` in powershell, use `Add-Content`, or `Out-File -Append`, or `[IO.File]::AppendAllLines`, or `[IO.File]::AppendText`, where you can specify encoding used.